# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0) in SQL while passing ? argument in query

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO JOB_AUDIT_HDR_LOG (APP_NM,BTCH_NUM,BTCH_RUN_STRT_TM,BTCH_RUN_STS_CD)
SELECT ? AS app_nm,
       COALESCE(btch_num, 0) + 1 AS batch_num,
       Now(),
       'RUNNING'
FROM   (SELECT 1) Dt1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT app_nm,
                              MAX(btch_num) AS btch_num
                       FROM   gmicntrldb.JOB_AUDIT_HDR_LOG
                       WHERE  app_nm = ?
                       GROUP  BY app_nm)Dt2
                    ON 1 = 1;
```

While am running this query getting an error like Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ?, which means you need to pass in a parameter array with entries for [0], and [1]. Looks like you're passing in only 1 (or maybe 0) parameters in your param array?